# how to enable layout in XmlHttpReeuqest in symfony

Tags: symfony1

Symfony detects if it receives a XmlHttpRequest and automatically turns off your debug bar and layout. However I'd like to have the response decorated with a specified layout. Also I don't want to add custom line of code in the `action` to enable the layout, I wish I can just make a configuration through yml files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to override the turning layout off with a custom view.yml for your module.

apps/frontend/modules/yourmodules/config.yml

```
ajaxSuccess:
  has_layout:     true
  layout:         theajaxlayout
```

However I am not sure that will be possible and you might have to do it in your action.

```
$this->setLayout("theajaxlayout");
```

Comment: I needed this one because of my ajax forms which are included to layout trough component so it was not used in XHRs.

So i created preExecute() with setLayout() in abstract controller and inherit it in all my related controllers.

Maybe someone find it helpfull.

THX to your response.